# How to parse json string to javascript object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have this kind of json string:

```
{"total":"3","data":[{"id":"4242","title":"Yeah Lets Go!","created":"1274700584","created_formated":"2010-07-24 13:19:24","path":"http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah"}{"id":"4242","title":"Yeah Lets Go!222","created":"1274700584","created_formated":"2010-07-24 13:19:24","path":"http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah222"}{"id":"4242","title":"Yeah Lets Go!333","created":"1274700584","created_formated":"2010-07-24 13:19:24","path":"http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah333"}]}
```

I would need to parse it to javascript object i believe? And then into html like:

```
<a href="http:www..domain.com/yeah">Yeah Lets Go!</a>
<p class="date">Created: 2010-07-24 13:19:24"</p>
```

but I have no clue how to parse it and so on.

I get that string from this:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
var item_id = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
$.get(base_url+'/ajax/get_itema/'+item_id+'/0/3/true', null, function(data, status, xhr) {
$('#contentCell').html(data);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Arrays and jQuery's getJSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699024/multidimensional-arrays-and-jquerys-getjson)

Comment: I'm not sure where your JSON is coming from, but the JSON you quote is malformed (missing a few commas)... see the note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `JSON.parse` function to convert a JSON string into a JS object. Most modern browsers include `JSON.parse`, but it is also included in [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) if you need a fallback for older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery, take a look at [**`.getJSON()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

The way you use `.getJSON()` is:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, [ data ], [ callback(data, textStatus) ] )
```

`url` is of course the `url` you're getting the data from. `[ data ]` is the stuff you send **to** the server. `[ callback(data, textStatus) ]` is a function that handles the `data` coming back **from** the server. You can generally leave out the second argument `textStatus`. The data coming back is understood to be JSON. `.getJSON()` is shorthand for a `.ajax()` call that specifies JSON data.

So in your case this would be something like (note that I changed the JSON coming back from the server to `response`... it's a less confusing nomenclature in your case than using `data`, since you have a `data` property in your JSON):

```
$.getJSON(base_url+'/ajax/get_itema/'+item_id+'/0/3/true', function(response) {
    ...
});
```

So, to recover things from `response` we simply access them using dot and square bracket notation. To get the first set of `data`:

```
response.data[0].title \\ <== "Yeah Lets Go!"
response.data[0].path \\ <== "http://domain.com/yeah"
```

The above looks in `response` which is our JSON object. Then it looks at the first `data` elment (there are 3) and pick the `title` in the first line and the `path` in the second.

Since you're using jQuery you can use **[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** to iterate over your 3 `data`. Like this:

```
$.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
    $("body").append('<a href="' + value.path + '">' + value.title + '</a>');
    $("body").append('<p class="date">Created: ' + value.created_formated + 
      '</p><br />');
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/x9WsY/)**

`.each()` sanely loops over a collection of items. The first argument of `.each()`, is the object you want to loop over. This is `response.data` not merely `response`. This is because we want to look at `response.data[0]`, `response.data[1]`, and `response.data[2]`. The second argument of `.each()` is the callback function, or what we want to do with each of the items we are iterating over. Within the callback function, the first argument is automatically the index of the item (0, 1, or 2 in your case). The second argument is the value of the item. In your case this is a separate object: `response.data[0]`, `response.data[1]`, and `response.data[2]` respectively. We can use dot notation to retrieve the things we want directly from these objects. In the above example we access `.path`. `.title` and `.created_formated` from each of the `value`s.

This make your entire function:

```
$.getJSON(base_url+'/ajax/get_itema/'+item_id+'/0/3/true', function(response) {
    $.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
        $("body").append('<a href="' + value.path + '">' + value.title + '</a>');
        $("body").append('<p class="date">Created: ' + value.created_formated + 
          '</p><br />');
    });                
});
```

Of course you probably want to append the response to (a) specific element/s.

**[Here's some good info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699024/multidimensional-arrays-and-jquerys-getjson/699046#699046)** on using `.getJSON()` to access multidimensional JSON data from another SO question.

**[Here's some general info about JSON in Javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html)**.

---

**Note:**

You need commas between your curly braces!

You have:

```
...p:\/\/domain.com\/yeah"}{"id":"4242","title"...
```

You need:

```
...p:\/\/domain.com\/yeah"}, {"id":"4242","title"...
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a div with id `result` to get the html, something like:

```
$.getJSON(base_url+'/ajax/get_itema/'+item_id+'/0/3/true', function(data) {
    $("#result").empty();
    $.each(data.data, function(i, d) {
        $("#result").append("<a href='" + d.path + "'>" + d.title + "</a>" + 
            "<p class='date'>Created: " + d.created_formated + "</p>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't found in any answers that the data which you posted are **NOT valid JSON string**. Probably it is your main problem and the reason why `$.get` can not convert the server response to object. The objects inside the data array **must be separated with commas**. So the data must looks like

```
{
    "total": "3",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "4242",
            "title": "Yeah Lets Go!",
            "created": "1274700584",
            "created_formated": "2010-07-24 13:19:24",
            "path": "http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah" 
        },
        {
            "id": "4242",
            "title": "Yeah Lets Go!222",
            "created": "1274700584",
            "created_formated": "2010-07-24 13:19:24",
            "path": "http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah222" 
        },
        {
            "id": "4242",
            "title": "Yeah Lets Go!333",
            "created": "1274700584",
            "created_formated": "2010-07-24 13:19:24",
            "path": "http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah333" 
        } 
    ]
}
```

I recommend you allays verify JSON strings in http://www.jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Also, he hasn't told jQuery that the response is to be parsed as JSON. I believe jq defaults to expecting it to be plain text or html, so one has to add 'json' as the last argument to `$.get` (after the callback), use `$.getJSON`, or use `$.ajax` and specify `dataType:'json'`. And right, even then, if you have malformed JSON it will fail.

Comment: @Alex JL: You are right, of cause one should use `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON`. I personally use always `$.ajax`. I wrote the answer only because I could not read about the error in "JSON" data. It was alredy enough answers about `$.getJSON` and how to use `for` or `$.each`, so I my answer was deliberately short.

Comment: Sure, I was just adding the information for completeness, not trying to correct you. I'm actually the one who gave you an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a templating engine that convert the JSON to HTML on the browser.

You can have a look at [pure.js](http://beebole.com/pure), it is very fast, and keep the HTML totally clean of any Javascript templating logic.
We use it to generate all the HTML from JSON data in our web app.(Yep... I'm a main contributor to the lib)

If you are more familiar with the <%...%> or ${...} kind of templates, there are plenty of them and for any taste if you [search on the web for javascript template](http://www.google.be/#hl=en&q=javascript+template).

Answer (score 0):

using data from Oleg answer

```
var json = {} // your json data reformated by Oleg

for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    document.write('<a href="' + json.data[i].path.replace(/\\/g, '') + '">' + json.data[i].title + '</a>');
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write('<p class="date">Created: ' + json.data[i].created_formated +'</p>');
    document.write('<br>');
}
```

remember that the "data" is an array of object