# How to parse JSON data, using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone please show me how I can get my JSON data and use it in javascript?

My data looks like this...

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 501",
    "2": "Parameter 501",
    "setting_value": "true",
    "3": "true"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 502",
    "2": "Parameter 502",
    "setting_value": "true",
    "3": "true"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 503",
    "2": "Parameter 503",
    "setting_value": "false",
    "3": "false"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 504",
    "2": "Parameter 504",
    "setting_value": "6",
    "3": "6"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 505",
    "2": "Parameter 505",
    "setting_value": "16",
    "3": "16"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 506",
    "2": "Parameter 506",
    "setting_value": "17",
    "3": "17"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 507",
    "2": "Parameter 507",
    "setting_value": "3",
    "3": "3"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 508",
    "2": "Parameter 508",
    "setting_value": "19",
    "3": "19"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "filename": "CONFIG 1",
    "1": "CONFIG 1",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 509",
    "2": "Parameter 509",
    "setting_value": "19",
    "3": "19"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 502",
    "2": "Parameter 502",
    "setting_value": "false",
    "3": "false"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 503",
    "2": "Parameter 503",
    "setting_value": "true",
    "3": "true"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 504",
    "2": "Parameter 504",
    "setting_value": "6",
    "3": "6"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 505",
    "2": "Parameter 505",
    "setting_value": "16",
    "3": "16"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 506",
    "2": "Parameter 506",
    "setting_value": "17",
    "3": "17"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 507",
    "2": "Parameter 507",
    "setting_value": "3",
    "3": "3"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 508",
    "2": "Parameter 508",
    "setting_value": "18",
    "3": "18"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 509",
    "2": "Parameter 509",
    "setting_value": "19",
    "3": "19"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "filename": "CONFIG 2",
    "1": "CONFIG 2",
    "setting_name": "Parameter 501",
    "2": "Parameter 501",
    "setting_value": "false",
    "3": "false"
}, false]
```

Basically I have four fields...
id, filename, setting_name and setting_value.

I need to know how I can get this and convert it into a javascript array, so that I may use it withing my logic. N

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON data, using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199029/how-to-parse-json-data-using-javascript)

Comment: @vol7ron Looks like an accidental double-post. This one came first

Comment: @Phil: I just like to close them both, for the sheer fact that it's a double and the question is horrible to look at.

Comment: @Carl Weis, please spend more time on your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse json string to javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653844/how-to-parse-json-string-to-javascript-object)

Comment: I went ahead and at least beautified it

Comment: @Carl Weis - I hate to discourage anybody from providing data with their question when so many posters provide none, but you really don't need to provide quite so much. Showing just the first two objects in the array would've been more than enough to give the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
o = JSON.parse('your string here');
console.log(o);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lenuk/

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse($record);
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML =obj.id[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax for `JSON` data is incorrect. Json data is enclosed within {} and not []. Still for parsing JSON data use json2.js library from the link.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

and use;

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);
```

Comment: The link you provide contradicts your statement that JSON data is only objects: "any JavaScript value, usually an object or array."