# How to parse returning JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse json string to javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653844/how-to-parse-json-string-to-javascript-object)

I am trying to get the values of returned JSON object by using javascript.

returned data

```
data: "[{"userID":"35047","testID":"5","subject":"1"..and more}]
```

in javascript, how do I loop through the userID/testID and value...etc.

Thanks for the help

Comment: [How to parse json string to javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653844/how-to-parse-json-string-to-javascript-object)

Comment: These questions aren't exactly equal. The other question uses jQuery.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use the `dataType: "json"` AJAX property to get back a JS object "by magic" .. `jQuery.each` can be used to enumerate arrays and objects easily.

Comment: @nalply: There's a jQuery tag on the question.

Comment: OK, didn't see that. Flagged it now as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

First parse with `JSON.parse()` then access them like an object. Example:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(your_data);
```

then

```
obj[0].userID
```

Explanation:

- The outer `[]` create an array and you can access the array elements by subscripts like `obj[0]`.
- The inner `{}` create an object, and you can access the fields by their names. Therefore `obj[0].userID`, `obj[0].testID`, etc.

**Note!**

`JSON.parse()` requires a shim (see [json.js/json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) in IE6/IE7. It may also be missing in other legacy browsers. You can however include it for all browsers because it detects that a native `JSON.parse()` exists.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can parse the JSON - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

And this post will show you how to iterate over key/value pairs in an object.

[How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()`

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse the JSON, if you are targeting only [this](http://caniuse.com/json) green browsers, then you can simply do:

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
```

If not you can load a extern parse library like [this one](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and then do it the same way.